# ui.router nested view inherit parent form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

Is it possible to have a ui.router nested view inherit it's parent's form?  I would like to organize my form to have nested views while leveraging angular's form validations on the parent controller.

I was achieving this initially without ui.router through using directives with a `require: ['^form']` (to handle specific form logic) but the controller's view became too large/unmaintainable.  Thus entered ui.router's nested views, but it appears that I'm losing the ability to pass all of the parent's form objects to the ui.router's nested view to ultimately pass into the directive that I was using earlier (the same directive using the `require['^form']`).

Anyone encounter this problem before?

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('form', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/form',
        controller: FormController,
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('form.child1', {
        url: '/child-one',
        controller: ChildOneController
    })
    .state('form.child2', {
        url: '/child-two',
        controller: ChildTwoController
    });
```

In this example **scope properties of the parent inherit down the state chain**. So all the scope properties of the FormController will be available in the child's, in this case, ChildOneController and ChildTwoController.

Also, note that **Resolved dependencies via resolve and Custom data properties** will inherit down from the parent scope.